# Using a capacitor for instantaneous power?

Tags: capacitor

Would a capacitor be useful for an instantaneous power? If I am switching between two AC power sources while a load is connected. The switching time is 2/60 s. Could a sufficient sized capacitor be used to keep the load powered?

Comment: dV = Ic dt/C using [A s / F ]=[V] decay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

As long as the size is sufficient, and the load is DC, and the load can tolerate the drop in voltage during the switching time, and suitable isolation like diodes or switches keeps all the power supplies tame during the switchover.

If the load is AC, then a rectifier and inverter will be needed in addition to the capacitor.

Comment: You did take note of the pesky little mention of "AC Power Sources", yes? ;-)

Comment: @Asmyldof I've made my answer explicit in the obvious assumptions.